# How to set rows' fixed height regardless the data in 'textarea' edittype fields

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using JqGrid with javascript. 
I would like to set a fixed height of 30px for each table row but I haven't managed to do so

this is my code:

I tried to use loadComplete function (in my code below) and add a CSS to the specific grid but didn't work.

```
jQuery("#IL_DealInsiderListsGrd").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local", // or server, considr delay
        height: 250,
        data: gridsMap["DM_InsiderListData"] ? gridsMap["DM_InsiderListData"].data : [], 
        colModel:[
            {label: 'List ID', name:'listId',index:'listId', width:150, sorttype:"text", key:true},
            {label: 'Status', name: 'status',index:'status', width:150},
            {label: 'Short Description', name:'shortDesc',index:'shortDesc', width:250,
             editable: true, edittype:'text'},
            {label: 'Description Info', name:'descInfo',index:'descInfo', width:250,
             editable: true, edittype:"textarea", formatter:'', editoptions:{rows:"3", dataInit: gridTextarea}},
            {label: 'Audit Date', name:'auditDate',index:'auditDate', width:150, sorttype:"date"}
        ],
        //multiselect: true,
        pager: '#IL_DealInsiderListsGrd_Pager',
        rowNum:6,
        rowList:[6,10,20],
        cellEdit : true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
         loadComplete: function() {
                    var grid = $("#IL_DealInsiderListsGrd");
                    var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        grid.setRowData ( ids[i], false, {height: 20+i*2} );
                    }
                    //grid.setGridHeight('auto');
                },
        beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, event) {
            setRowEditable($(this), rowid, !($(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid).status === 'Cleansed'))
            return true;
        },
        afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            if(!value.trim()) {
                showAlert("Field is mandatory");
                $(this).jqGrid('restoreCell', iRow, iCol);
            }
            else {
                $(this).jqGrid('setCell', rowid, "auditDate", getDatetimeString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the css class of your rows with chrome debugger.

Then set the following in your css (replace `your-css-class` with the class you have found):

```
.your-css-class {
    height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't change the CSS since it's related to other grids as well. how ever I tried to use the jqgrid '.addClass' for the specific grid- it cuts the whole grid instead of restricting the row size